# Declaring a variable in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am trying to declare a variable called `NEW_VARIABLE` that equals `(end_date - start_date)`. I then use the variable `NEW_VARIABLE` below as an interval `(date1 + NEW_VARIABLE + interval '1 days')`.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1_variables AS (
    SELECT
        '2016-10-29'::date as start_date,
        dateadd(day,-10,getdate())::date as end_date,
        '2015-10-31'::date as date1
        (end_date - start_date) as NEW_VARIABLE
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tbl1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tbl1 (cobrand_id int, xsum numeric(30,15));

insert into tmp_tbl1 (cobrand_id, xsum )
select q1.cobrand_id, q1.a/q2.d as xsum from (
    SELECT cobrand_id, sum(calc) AS a FROM jwn_calc s, tmp1_variables
    where s.optimized_transaction_date > start_date AND s.optimized_transaction_date <= end_date + interval '1 days' GROUP BY cobrand_id
) as q1
inner join (
    SELECT cobrand_id AS c, 
    sum(CASE WHEN optimized_transaction_date > date1 AND optimized_transaction_date <= date1 + NEW_VARIABLE + interval '1 days' THEN Calc END) / 
    sum(CASE WHEN optimized_transaction_date > date1 AND optimized_transaction_date <= date1 + interval '91 days' THEN Calc END) AS d
    FROM jwn_calc, tmp1_variables
    GROUP BY cobrand_id
) as q2 on q1.cobrand_id = q2.c;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would do wonders to explain what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I was looking to fix the syntax on this one as opposed to seek a desired result.  How can I declare (end_date - start_date) as a variable when I created the variables end_date and start_date in the same select statement?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *no* variables in SQL at all. Just tables, columns and expressions.
So, obviously you cannot "declare a variable" to begin with. The wrong terminology easily inspires an inadequate approach ...

Also, `dateadd()` and `getdate()`? You may be thinking of MS SQL Server. Those functions do not exist in Postgres.

Either way, use a subquery (or a CTE) to build new expression from constant input:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp1_variables AS (
SELECT *, end_date - start_date AS new_variable
FROM  (
   SELECT date '2016-10-29' AS start_date
        , CURRENT_DATE - 10 AS end_date
        , date '2015-10-31' AS date1
   ) sub
);
```

Displaying valid Postgres syntax.

In Postgres, you can just add / subtract `integer` to / from a `date` (but not a `timestamp`).
And if you add an `interval` to a `date`, you get a `timestamp`.

Of course, you can cast the result back to `date`:

```
(date1 + new_variable + interval '1 days')::date
```

But rather compute a `date` to begin with:

```
date1 + new_variable + 1
```

Aside: unquoted identifiers are cast to lower case in Postgres.